# subclass uitableviewcell and override layoutsubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to make cell selectionBackgroundView not on full width in plain UItableView. For this I made UItableViewCell subclass and override layoutsubviews method

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + 10.0f, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width - 20.0f, self.frame.size.height);

}
```

My cellForRowAtIndexPath method looks like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"CELL %i %i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    GroupedTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[GroupedTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];


        UIView *cellBgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        cellBgView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 80);
        [cellBgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:242 / 255.0 green:242 / 255.0 blue:242 / 255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellBgView];
    }



        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    UIView *selectionView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [selectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:181 / 255.0 green:211 / 255.0 blue:53 / 255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    selectionView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 80);
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionView;
    return cell;
}
```

But only for first row selectedView works correct. For other rows I have selectedView with clear color. Please, help me.

Comment: @TheSaad, I did not add this method yet. It is empty.

Comment: in your didselect method do this

Comment: [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

Answer (score 4):

All I need was to set frame with numbers.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 0, 300, 80);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead add the background in the subclassed cell itself,
do like this it is an example how you can manage the selection and deselection state in the cell change it to your requirements

```
   //in your subclassed cell
   #import "GroupedTableCell.h"

   @implementation GroupedTableCell

   - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
      self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
      if (self) {
       // Initialization code
       //add the background view hear only, changes the frame in the layoutsubviews
       UIView *cellBgView = [[UIView alloc] init];


     [cellBgView setTag:12345];//using tag to access in the layoutsubviews
     [self addSubview:cellBgView];//hear u added the background view



    }
    return self;
 }

 //manage the cell selection and deselection state hear
  - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
   // Configure the view for the selected state  
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    UIView *cellBgView = [self viewWithTag:12345];
    if(selected)
    {

      [cellBgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:242 / 255.0 green:242 / 255.0 blue:242 / 255.0
                                                   alpha:1.0]]; //your selected background color
    }
    else
   {
       [cellBgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; //your deselected background color

   }

}

//setting the frames of views within the cell
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    UIView *cellBgView = [self viewWithTag:12345];
    cellBgView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 80);//always set the frame in layoutSubviews

}
```

in your controller  just do like this

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      GroupedTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
      if(cell == nil)
      {
          cell = [[GroupedTableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
      }

     return cell;

 }
```

Hope this helps u :)